# List of all different IfcEntities in IfcFile

Tags: c#, ifc, xbim

### Summary

- i have an ifc file with different IfcEntities like IfcWall, IfcBeam, IfcColumn etc.
- i'm struggling to find a way to list all different entities in this ifc file
- the list should contain every ifcentity occurence just once {"IfcWall", "IfcColumn", "IfcBeam", ...}
- debugged also the code to see if there was any property which held the value i was searching for

### My Code:

- i've used the xbim Essential quick start guide
- googled also
- looked through the issues on github

```
using (var model = IfcStore.Open(_FilePath))
{
    var allInstances = model.Instances;
    var testList = model.Instances.OfType<IIfcBuildingElement>();

    var nameList = new List<string>();
    var objTypeList = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in testList)
    {
        var objType = item.IsTypedBy;
        var firstObjType = objType.ElementAt(0);
        var relType = firstObjType.RelatingType;

        var name = item.Name;
        nameList.Add(name);
    }
}
```

### What i expect:

- simple list with all IfcEntities
- like {"IfcWall", "IfcColumn", "IfcBeam", ...}

Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @martin1cerny

the answer was quite simple:

```
var testList = model.Instances.OfType<IIfcBuildingElement>().GroupBy(e => e.GetType());
```

[issue/question on github](https://github.com/xBimTeam/XbimEssentials/issues/374)